# express app listen if mongodb is up and re-establish connection

Tags: node.js, express

i have this code that opens up a connection to mongodb:

```
db_connect_mongo = init: (callback) ->
  self = this
  mongo_options = db:
      safe: true
  mongoose.connect DB_URL, mongo_options
  db = self.db_mongo = mongoose.connection

  db.on "error", (error) ->
    logger.error "ERROR connecting to: " + DB_URL, logCategory
    callback error, null

  db.on "connected", ->
    logger.info "SUCCESSFULLY connected to: " + DB_URL, logCategory
    callback true, db

  db.on "disconnected", ->
    logger.info "DISCONNECTED from the database: " + DB_URL, logCategory

# check and connect to Redis

exports = module.exports = db_connect_mongo
```

i then call this in my app.coffee like:

```
#Connect to database
dbconnection = require "./utils/dbconnect"
dbconnection.init (result) ->
  logger.info "Database initialized: " + result, logCategory
```

when i shut down the mongo db, i get a `info: [DATABASE Connection] DISCONNECTED from the database: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/zmgc-mongo` so in my logger.coffee i would like to 'listen' if the mongodb comes up so that a connection be made.

what would be a good approach to catch all the events of de/re-connection to the db?

Comment: According to the documentation, there is a [`reconnected`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection) event that should be fired (by default, mongoose will automatically reconnect when it got disconnected). However, in my case I can't get it to work. I wonder if that's because the connection instance (`mongoose.connection`) will be replaced by a new instance (since it had to reconnect), and the event listeners aren't copied to it.

Comment: perhaps i was not clear in my post, i will update it, but it does work and the driver does reconnect. what i was after was to be able to be able to catch all the events of de/re-connection to the db.